# Is there a tool like CGDB for LLDB?

Tags: lldb, cgdb

I'm looking for a tool like CGDB for LLDB.

Make debugging in the terminal easier.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a GUI but a very useful "extension": https://github.com/snare/voltron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lldb has a curses based gui that you can switch to with the `gui` command in lldb.  It isn't complete yet, and in particular doesn't have a command-line window.  So you can step, view threads, frames, locals and source, but you have to switch out of GUI mode to type commands.

Comment: As @Jim Ingham said it is very primitive.